# Priority of ActiveMQ configuration via URI

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have a few questions here regarding similar area of the ActiveMQ configuration and priority. I am currently configuring an ActiveMQ broker to turn off the message persistence.

Based on the documentation I know it can be achieved via broker config in:

- xml configuration file ()
- URI on the client side (tcp://localhost:61616?persistent=false)
- URI on the broker side - xml configuration file (tcp://localhost:61616?persistent=false).

My first question is what happens when I setup persistence=false in URI on the broker's side but a client will connect with URI persistence=true?

What happens if I set up  but in URI on the broker's side I provide persistent=false and a client will not provide any additional settings when connecting?

Similar question about connectionTimeout or maximumConnections params. Based on the doc (http://activemq.apache.org/tcp-transport-reference.html) it "can be configured on a JMS client's connection URI string or on a Brokers transport bind URI". What if there is a different setting on the broker's side and on the client's side? What if two clients connect with different settings? It could be that connectionTimeout may be related to only one particular connection (when a client provides this parameter) but I don't see how maximumConnections could have a meaning per one connection.

From the security perspective my understanding is that when I limit the max connection number to 100 on the server/broker side clients should not be allowed to increase that number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually persistence on the Broker is controlled only in the XML configuration or in the configuration of an embedded Broker, the transport connectors have no control over this nor can a client change this.

As for the connection configuration that is on a TransportConnector only basis so setting the maximum number of allowed connections etc those values cannot be altered by the client, that would be quite bad if it were.  The client settings only affect the behaviour of the client not the broker.  If you set the max on the broker's TCP transport connector configuration to 100 then only 100 clients will be allowed at any given time and no client can change that.

Comment: so does it mean that setting persistence=false on the uri on the client's or the broker's side has no effect?

Comment: That's what it means, there is no such option.